# Remove multiple items from array in range

Tags: php

I Have an array like the code below and
now if the value is set to 3, the array 1 and 2 should be deleted ..
and the result output would be the remaining arrays including the value..  how can I implement that ??

```
$value = 3;
$arr = array(
             1 => array(
                   "id" => 1,
                   "name" => "John",
             ),
             2 => array(
                 "id" => 2,
                 "name" => "Jack",
             ),
             3 => array(
                 "id" => 3,
                 "name" => "Jason",
             ),
             4 => array(
                 "id" => 4,
                 "name" => "Jane",
             ),
             5 => array(
                 "id" => 5,
                 "name" => "Joe",
             ),
         );
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try array slice, this will slice array and give you required result

```
$value = 2;
$a= array(
         "1" => array(
               "id" => 1,
               "name" => "John",
         ),
         "2" => array(
             "id" => 2,
             "name" => "Jack",
         ),
         "3" => array(
             "id" => 3,
             "name" => "Jason",
         ),
         "4" => array(
             "id" => 4,
             "name" => "Jane",
         ),
         "5" => array(
             "id" => 5,
             "name" => "Joe",
         ),
     );
print_r(array_slice($a,$value-1));
```